# ¿Filtrar por los campos que retorna una subconsulta?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo un query de SQL server que me retorna varios campos, el query es con varios join para traer los datos que necesito, ahora, necesito esos datos hacerles un Update, cómo puedo hacer el update únicamente a esos registros que me retorna la consulta?.

Ya intente con `EXISTS` y nada, las subconsultas me funcionan bien cuando retorno un solo campo lo hago con el `IN` pero en este caso la subconsulta me retorna varios campos

Mi consulta es esta

```sql
SELECT t2.HPA_Ref_1, t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID, t1.HPAF_Referencia_ID, t1.HPAF_EstadoRevision, t2.HPA_EstadoRevision, t3.ACT_Departamento_ID, t3.ACT_Ciudad_ID, t1.HPAF_UsuarioCreacion, t1.HPAF_FechaCreacion, t1.HPAF_UsuarioActualizacion, t1.HPAF_FechaActualizacion, t2.HPA_SoporteVigente
FROM [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministradoFactura] t1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado] t2 ON t2.HPA_Nit_ID = t1.HPAF_Nit_ID AND t2.HPA_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 AND t2.HPA_Servicio_ID = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID AND t2.HPA_Periodo_ID = t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[Activos] t3 ON t3.ACT_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ContratoActivo] t4 ON t4.RCA_RefActivo_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ServicioAdmin_Activo] t5 ON t5.RSA_Ref_Activo = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 AND t5.RSA_IDServicio = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID
WHERE t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID = t5.RSA_PeriodoVigente AND t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID = '6' AND t2.HPA_EstadoRevision = '1'
```

Y quiero hacer un `UPDATE` así:

```sql
UPDATE [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado] SET HPA_EstadoReporte = '5', HPA_SoporteVigente = '1' 
WHERE IN (
SELECT t2.[HPA_Nit_ID],t2.[HPA_Ref_1],t2.[HPA_Servicio_ID],t2.[HPA_Periodo_ID]
FROM [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministradoFactura] t1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado] t2 ON t2.HPA_Nit_ID = t1.HPAF_Nit_ID AND t2.HPA_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 AND t2.HPA_Servicio_ID = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID AND t2.HPA_Periodo_ID = t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[Activos] t3 ON t3.ACT_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ContratoActivo] t4 ON t4.RCA_RefActivo_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ServicioAdmin_Activo] t5 ON t5.RSA_Ref_Activo = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 AND t5.RSA_IDServicio = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID
WHERE t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID = t5.RSA_PeriodoVigente AND t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID = '6' AND t2.HPA_EstadoRevision = '1'
)
```

Pero no funciona.

Estoy probando haciendo que el select me retorne los registros que me retorna la consulta original, para validar que el `WHERE` me funcione, y no lo he conseguido

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado]
WHERE IN (
SELECT t2.[HPA_Nit_ID],t2.[HPA_Ref_1],t2.[HPA_Servicio_ID],t2.[HPA_Periodo_ID]
FROM [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministradoFactura] t1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado] t2 ON t2.HPA_Nit_ID = t1.HPAF_Nit_ID AND t2.HPA_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 AND t2.HPA_Servicio_ID = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID AND t2.HPA_Periodo_ID = t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[Activos] t3 ON t3.ACT_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ContratoActivo] t4 ON t4.RCA_RefActivo_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ServicioAdmin_Activo] t5 ON t5.RSA_Ref_Activo = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 AND t5.RSA_IDServicio = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID
WHERE t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID = t5.RSA_PeriodoVigente AND t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID = '6' AND t2.HPA_EstadoRevision = '1'
)
```

Los campos que estoy retornando son la PK de la tabla `[ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado]`

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de reconvertir tu query a una update por varias columnas es introducirla en una tabla de expresión común.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT t2.[HPA_Nit_ID],t2.[HPA_Ref_1],t2.[HPA_Servicio_ID],t2.[HPA_Periodo_ID]
FROM [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministradoFactura] t1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado] t2 ON t2.HPA_Nit_ID = t1.HPAF_Nit_ID 
            AND t2.HPA_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 
            AND t2.HPA_Servicio_ID = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID 
            AND t2.HPA_Periodo_ID = t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[Activos] t3 ON t3.ACT_Ref_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ContratoActivo] t4 ON t4.RCA_RefActivo_1 = t1.HPAF_Ref_1
INNER JOIN [ActivosO].[R_ServicioAdmin_Activo] t5 ON t5.RSA_Ref_Activo = t1.HPAF_Ref_1 
            AND t5.RSA_IDServicio = t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID
WHERE   t1.HPAF_Periodo_ID = t5.RSA_PeriodoVigente 
    AND t1.HPAF_Servicio_ID = '6' 
    AND t2.HPA_EstadoRevision = '1'
) -- Ahora tu query se llama CTE
UPDATE A SET HPA_EstadoReporte = '5', HPA_SoporteVigente = '1' 
FROM [ActivosO].[HistoricoPeriodoAdministrado] A 
    INNER JOIN Cte C
            on  c.[HPA_Nit_ID] = a.[HPA_Nit_ID] 
            AND c.[HPA_Servicio_ID] = a.[HPA_Servicio_ID]
            AND c.[HPA_Periodo_ID] = a.[HPA_Periodo_ID];
```

A la salida del Cte realizamos la update sobre el alias A, donde A es la tabla HistoricoPeriodicoAdministrado que se combina con la query por cada uno de los campos que forman la clave primaria.